# COMException while instantiating a form containing an ActiveX control in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, activex

The problem: While running a WPF application I get:

**Exception**

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll

**Inner Exception**: Class unregistered

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHCOM);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)&rd=true

**Exception printed in console**:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Klasa niezarejestrowana. (Wyjatek od HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   w System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   w System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   w System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   w System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   w HomeSecurity.VideoStream.InitializeComponent() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\VideoStream.Designer'HomeSecurity.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: HomeSecurity.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
.cs:wiersz 48
   w HomeSecurity.VideoStream..ctor() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\VideoStream.cs:wiersz 13
   w HomeSecurity.MainWindow..ctor() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\MainWindow.xaml.cs:wiersz 23
The thread 0x1198 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

In the WPF project I have `MainWindow` with default automatically generated [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language):

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Inside .cs file I have only instantied `VideoStream`

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            VideoStream VideoStream = new VideoStream();//THAT LINE PRODUCES THE EXCEPTION
        }
    }
```

`VideoStream` is a `Form`. This form contains an ActiveX control called `AxisMediaControl Class`, and it looks like that. There is no additional code in .cs file.

NOTE: The identical Form in `WinForms` application causes no problems. Removing the ActiveX control from this Form removes the exception (in WPF).

[image]

---

**These references are added:**

[image]

[image]

---

**Inner Exception**:

[image]
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHCOM);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)&rd=true

Comment: Check inner exception.

Comment: @RohitVats Thank you for your time. I have added Inner Exception just at the bottom. Please refresh

Comment: @RohitVats I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: It seems some COM exception and not related to WPF. Sorry but i am not aware of it. :(

Comment: @RohitVats I have used this Activex in WinForms app and it worked. Here it does not. Maybe it is lacking reference?

Comment: What is the ErrorCode value of the COMException?

Comment: @JohnD System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class unregistered. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: @JohnD At the top of the original post I have posted full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JohnD I should compile in 32 bit.

Comment: Does your winforms app run successfully on the same machine where the WPF app is failing?  If yes, it might be a 64/32-bit compatibility issue..  is your WPF app 64-bit?  what about the winforms app?

Comment: @JohnD Yes, this is the same machine. After changing debug settings to x86 the problem dissaperad but then the next appeared I am making a topic about it right now.

Comment: @JohnD Would you kindly look up at the following link? I know this is much to ask but I am stuck in a loop hole with these integration problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912025/argumentexception-occurs-when-inserting-form-containing-activex-control-into-win

Answer (score 0):

One should compile and run the application as 32-bit to avoid this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too obvious, but have you installed the Axis SDK? Or have you registered the required ActiveX DLL files?

For building a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS you have to register the 32-bit DLL file (as administrator):

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe "\path\to\AxisSDKActiveX.dll" :: 32-bit ActiveX
>   C:\Windows\regsvr32.exe "\path\to\AxisSDKActiveX.dll" :: 64-bit ActiveX

Notice the SysWOW64 folder. It actually contains the 32-bit tools and DLL files. **This is really important to understand!**

To see what libraries are currently registered, use [RegDllView application](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html). You could also use the <kbd>F6</kbd> key in the application to register a new library.